# Equivalent of drupal_add_library()

Tags: 6, webforms

I am working on formbuilder for a Drupal 6 project. On of the issues I am facing is that the "markup" component does not use the wysiwyg editor properly.

I found this fix: https://drupal.org/node/1532536#comment-5938202 But apparently it is meant for Drupal 7.

How do I do `drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.textarea');` in Drupal 6?